# Weird arraylist result?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, calendarview

I am adding to an array list every SATURDAY and SUNDAY date of the month, for the first 3 months.

However, when I iterate through the array, to check if the values are actually correct, I seem to get only a few elements (with the size of the array still being correct though -> E.g. only two elements in the array, while the size is 26).

Any help?

```
info.setContentView(R.layout.calendar_dialog);
        CalendarView calendarView = info.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);

        Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar max = Calendar.getInstance();
        max.add(Calendar.MONTH,3);
        calendarView.setMinimumDate(currentDate);
        calendarView.setMaximumDate(max);


        Calendar temp = Calendar.getInstance();
        ArrayList<Calendar> calendars = new ArrayList<>();
        calendars.add(temp);

        while(temp.get(Calendar.MONTH) < max.get(Calendar.MONTH)) {

            temp.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

            if(temp.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 1 || temp.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 7) {
                calendars.add(temp);
            }
        }

        calendarView.setDisabledDays(calendars);

        info.findViewById(R.id.calendar_ok).setOnClickListener(v -> info.dismiss());
        info.show();
```

Comment: Why did you mark as accepted a repeated answer given after mine? (and less accurate, BTW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that You use only single instance of `Calendar` in `temp` variable. You modify it in each iteration of Your `while` loop and store the same reference in `calendars` list.

In the end, `calendars` list contains many (You say 26) items but all of them refers exactly the same `Calendar` instance which was modified in each iteration.

Solution is to build completely new Calendar instance before adding it to the list:

```
...
if(temp.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 1 || temp.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 7){
    calendars.add((Calendar)temp.clone());
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the same object (`temp`) to the arraylist over and over again.
Do this instead:

```
calendars.add(temp.clone());
```

Comment: Casting is missing, it should be: `calendars.add((Calendar)temp.clone());`

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes there:

1) The condition `while(temp.get(Calendar.MONTH) < max.get(Calendar.MONTH))` is not taking into account the change of the year if the period is close the final/beginning of a new year. Comparing November 2018 and February 2019 will fail with that condition.

2) You should not add the same instance of the calendar over and over again: `calendars.add(temp);`. Instead, make a deep clone of the instance (`temp.clone()`), and add to the list a new instance with the proper values every time.